# Tumblr API v2 c# oauth

Tags: c#, api, oauth, tumblr

I am trying use use Tumblr API V2 oAuth with c# OAuthBase.cs. [oAuth c# Base Class](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs)

Then I inherited [tumblr oAuth Example](http://tinypaste.com/0800495e).

When I try this:

```
oAuthTumblr oAuth = new oAuthTumblr();
oAuth.xAuthAccessTokenGet(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

if (oAuth.TokenSecret.Length > 0)
{
  string bName = "good";
  string url = string.Format("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{0}.tumblr.com/followers",bName);     
  xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTumblr.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
  webBrowser1.DocumentText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xml);
}
```

I get error 400 bad request

Please help

Thanks